# Angular ng-show from variable set on scope of directive in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-show

I would like to be able to set ng-show off a variable I set on the scope variable within the link function of an Angular customer directive.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('testDir', function () {
    return {
      template: <div ng-show="{{showme}}"> hello </div>,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) { //
        scope.showme=true; 
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately, when I do this it doesn't work as expected.  If I set scope.showme=true, then my directive is hidden.  If I set it =false then it is shown.  How am I screwing this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-show` needs an expression not the value of an expression, so remove interpolation `{{}}` from the expression.

Do:

```
 template: <div ng-show="showme"> hello </div>,
```